# Quickblox store chat into cache for android like Ios Quickblox sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, chat, quickblox, quickblox-android

I am currently working on android chat application with using [Quickblox](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android) SDK.its good for developing chat,video and audio call.but for android there are some limitations.I already waste my 3 days.there is some limitation which I am facing.

1). I am not getting Message during DialogsActivity.How can I update particular dialog when getting messagew from any user? in ios SDK, it's already handled in demo projects.

2). in ios SDK They can easily store whole chat in the cache memory  using Service manager Class.but for android there is no method to store data.How can I store chat history in the cache memory using quickblox android like ios?

3). in Quickblox SDK we need to login every time.Is there any method for get login status?

Help for this Problems

Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you have get the answer?

Comment: did you get answer?

Comment: no, i didn't get yet

Comment: Hi, did you get any success on this ?